# How do I send telnet option codes?

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

I've written a socket listener in Java that just sends some data to the client.

If I connect to the server using telnet, I want the server to send some telnet option codes. Do I just send these like normal messages?

Like, if I wanted the client to print "hello", I would do this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
out.print("hello");
out.flush();
```

But when I try to send option codes, the client just prints them. Eg, the IAC char (0xff) just gets printed as a strange y character when I do this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
out.print((char)0xff);
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the default character encoding I would expect 0xff to be turned into two characters.

I suggest you use the plain OutputStream *without* a PrintWriter.  That way the bytes will be sent without translation.

Answer (score 2):

[I just answered that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532344/send-data-over-telnet-without-pressing-enter/4532463#4532463)